# Is it possible to limit the number of emails displayed in Outlook mailbox?

Tags: outlook, ms-office, outlook-2016

I work on a team that has a group mailbox in Outlook with over 82,000 mails. It takes a few minutes just to load the most recent mails, sometimes hangs and occasionally crashes.

Is there a setting to say "just display the most recent 1,000 emails" or something? And then we can use search tools to find anything else?

This is Office Professional Plus 2016. The mailbox currently receives around 200+ mails a day, history goes back almost a year.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the cached mode of connection to the Exchange server in Outlook you may limit the amount of data saved locally, for example, you may keep only items for the last year or three months. See [Plan and configure Cached Exchange Mode in Outlook 2016 for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/installation/cached-exchange-mode). Also you may roll out a group policy for that, see [Enable Exchange Cached Mode through group policy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/67c174f9-4036-4a53-adbb-a455232ba8fd/enable-exchange-cached-mode-through-group-policy?forum=winserverGP) for more information.